# kendo listview remove method parameter not correct

Tags: kendo-listview

My list view has a string and a delete button(this is with k-delete-button class). When I press delete I need to call a special method on my viewModel. and this should not update my datasource..

I'm using my own "remove" method as below on the kendo listview.

```
m("div" , {
     id:"listView",
     "data-role": "listview",
     "data-template":"template",
     selectable: "multiple",
     "data-bind":"source: items, events: {remove: onItemRemove} ",    

   })
```

on my view Model :

onItemRemove = (e:any) => {this.removeWavelegnthFromList(e.model);    }

I'm using e.model to get the value corresponding to the item that I'm trying to delete. But this is set to a wrong value. It doesn't return the value I've selected for delete.

I couldnt use e.sender.select() method to get my value and it throw "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined(…)" error.

please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong.